# How to display data URI for PDF in Chrome App?

Tags: window, uri, google-chrome-app

I have a data URI generated from a JavaScript PDF library (jsPDF) that seems to be OK, because when I display it with console.log and paste it into a browser URL field, it works. However, I can't get it to display from within the Chrome App, either in a Chrome App window or an ordinary browser window. The URI starts like this:

```
var uri = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMK ...";
```

When I do this:

```
chrome.app.window.create(uri);
```

The window opens, but it is trying to load the URI:

chrome-extension://gapkhdeaendagkjpchhemfhbpfcjgmep/data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMK ...

and in the window there is the message "This webpage is not found".

When I do this:

```
window.open(uri);
```

or

```
window.open(chrome.runtime.getURL(uri));
```

absolutely nothing happens. No browser window or tab opens, and no message is written to the console.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chrome.app.window.create` will only load a resource from the packaged app, so you can't escape the `chrome-extension://gapkhdea.../` address space there.

`window.open` when called from a packaged app window will use the default system handler to open the URL. I don't know of any common system configurations which have a default handler registered for the data scheme, which is probably why nothing happens.

What you want, if your goal is to display arbitrary untrusted content within a packaged app, is the [webview tag](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview.html). You can embed a Webview element directly into an app window's contents. You can use a `data` URI for its `src` attribute, which can be assigned dynamically.

Depending on your Chrome version, you may encounter permissions issues when the Webview attempts to load the PDF viewer plugin, but I just tested this with some PDF data and got beautifully displayed PDF rendering inside of a packaged app.

Comment: Thanks, Ken... will try and mark this as the answer if I'm successful.

Comment: Didn't try a webview, but did try an <a> element with target=_blank, with the data URL set as the href, and it did open the PDF in a browser window. I believe I tried that a few Chrome versions ago and it didn't work, although I'm not sure. Anyway, I now have what I want.

Comment: Now I did try a webview, but all I got was a black rectangle. Inspecting the element, the PDF appears to be there, but I don't see it. Just black.

Comment: That black rectangle was a Chrome bug. Went back to beta (I was on dev), and it works! So, two way to do it: webview, as Ken suggests, and as a link with target=_blank.