# Unable to open PDF Blob in ObjectURL using chrome.app.window.create

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have a PDF storred in a `Blob`

```
var pdfBlob = new Blob(buffers, {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

From that I create an Object URL

```
var pdfURL = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
```

That gives something like `blob:chrome-extension%3A//mlbdgii.`

If I manually copy the URL to a Chrome tab the PDF is successfully opened. However if I try to open it using `chrome.app.window.create` I just get a "This webpage is not found" error.

So the question is, can I open an Object URL using  this method? If not, is there a workaround to get a PDF stored in an ObjectURL to be displayed in a Chrome App or Chrome Tab ?

Comment: I believe the answer you want is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388786/how-to-display-data-uri-for-pdf-in-chrome-app

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27256841/3826713 , I had a similar issue and webview was my workaround for it.